# What do you call a person who makes easy things difficult?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What you you call a person that can take a simple, easily understood concept or task and turn it in to a complicated procedure?

Comment: That’s called a *manager* I think.

Comment: It saddens me greatly that I can't upvote your comment more than once.

Comment: Over-Engineered ?

Comment: Although not technically a real word, I wouldn't see anything wrong with using overcomplicator.

Comment: You might want to reference a Rube Goldberg machine, such as https://www.teachengineering.org/collection/cub_/lessons/cub_images/cub_simp_machines_lesson05_figure1.jpg .

Comment: Hi Dave... I have removed the "proper-nouns" tag and have applied the "single-word-requests" tag to this question. Please consider adding an example sentence to attract responses.

Comment: Or "an academic".

Comment: I've been told that "English teacher" fits.

Comment: Please see: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: "End user" would be my nomination.

Comment: One can find some quite brow-raising things when searching Google creatively. I thought to myself, "Well, *accommodate* is a word, so how about *accommodator* as someone who accommodates others, and *decommodator* as someone who doesn't..." So, Accommodator is a thing, much to my surprise!!

Comment: Profit center ?

Answer (score 4):

According to at least two online [dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complicator), ["complicator"](http://cs.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=complicator) is a real word that might help.

Even if it isn't in the Oxford dictionary (yet), we can make it so. Such is the nature of language.

Comment: You always have to make things complicated, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

**[obfuscator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscator)**

> one that obfuscates

where **[obfuscate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate)** means

> to make (something) more difficult to understand

This is often used in the context of intentionally making something more confusing rather than doing so through incompetence, but it wasn't clear from your question which side of that aspect you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest,

***overthinker***

> One who overthinks.
>
> overthink: to think or analyze too much. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/overthinker)

***beanplater***

> beanplate:  *Slang* to overthink [DefiniThing](http://definithing.com/beanplate/)

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't crack the "proper" dictionaries, **confusticate** was used by Tolkien in *The Hobbit* and forms of the word appear in the Urban Free Dictionary. Thus *confusticator*: one who confuses things beyond their natural state.

Now, before I start getting down votes, how about **confuter** the noun form of *confute*: confound [Webster's].

But as long as we're considering neologisms ... *confusionist*, huh?

Comment: You can even derive a philosophy from that - confusianism. Very established in China.

Comment: Confusticate cracks OED, don't get more proper than that!

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

[**hinderance**](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=hindrance&oq=hindera&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i59j0l3.6718j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Google Definition:

> hin·drance
>
> ˈhindrəns
>
> noun
>
> a thing that provides resistance, delay, or obstruction to something or someone.

I think this word could be used to label your hypothetical person, but it could also be used to label people who make a bad situation worse.

If Urban Dictionary is an acceptable source, then [**frustrator**](http://cs.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frustrator) would also work:

> Noun
>
> some who frequently provokes frustration

Answer (score 0):

Consider **hair-splitter**.

Hair-splitting is the introduction of unnecessary complications. It is the making of unreasonably fine distinctions. No matter how small, the person will differentiate between subjects.

For example:

> "The legal experts have a particularly hair-splitting mentality".

Or

> - Person 1: "Colin just spent the past half-hour telling me the difference between magenta and pink"
> - Person 2: "He is such a hair splitter"

Comment: But, but, but -- A "hair-splitter" is trying to *simplify* things by getting the definitions down as narrow as possible.

Comment: @HotLicks - I think that this word has a negative connotation of exageration.

Answer (score 0):

You've already had general answers like *complicator* and *obfuscator*. Here's another slant on your question, yielding a few more specific terms.

As it stands, the question asks for a label for a person who **can** (i.e. has the ability to) make the simple complex. One label is [deep thinker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep_thinker), though such people might prefer to substitute the word *profound* for *complex*. For example:

> Someone asked: “What is the meaning of life?”
>   Some random dude replied: “To give life a meaning.” [- daedreth, quoted by Nico Lang](http://thoughtcatalog.com/nico-lang/2013/08/25-unintentionally-profound-statements-that-will-change-your-life-today/)

If your question emphasises the word *procedure*, the apparent simplicity may be due to underestimating the problem. [Researchers](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/researcher) sometimes take simple ideas and produce extremely detailed means of reliably carrying them out. Consider the following thesis which documents how a robot may be set up so that you can simply tell it where to go. It's harder than it sounds - even people don't always get it right. (I got this from a google search and am counting on CMU's reputation for the result's *reliability*.)

> Natural Language Direction Following for Robots in Unstructured Unknown Environments [- Ph.D dissertation by Felix Duvallet](http://repository.cmu.edu/dissertations/582/)

For the political cynic, the ability to produce a *complicated procedure* from a *simple, easily understood concept or task* is a skill commonly attributed to *some* [bureaucrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureaucrat).

And finally, *we who answer EL&U questions* can at times produce quite a lot out of very little :P .